# How to send full screen intent notifications using onesignal in react native

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I am using react-native-onesignal in my application to send push notification to my users. My business now required me to send full screen notification that show up on lock screen as well, like uber or mygate.
How can i achieve this using onesignal. I've read about Service extenders in onesignal but not sure if they can be used.